# Create Object of values from Array all equal to 1

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an Array `properties = ['foo', 'bar']`.

I want to create and Object like `query = {foo:1, bar:1}`

Currently I'm doing..

```
 const query = {};
  
  for (let property of properties) {
    query[property] = 1;
  }
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) paired with `map()`:

```js
const query = Object.fromEntries(properties.map(property => [property, 1]));
```

Or using `reduce()` as suggested by @Jamiec, but I'm not sure these solutions are clearer than a simple loop (at least they're clever :P).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with `reduce` (but im not sure it's simpler!):

```js
var properties =['foo', 'bar']
var query = properties.reduce( (acc,prop) => {
  acc[prop] = 1;
  return acc
},{});
console.log(query);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) Method. Traverse array using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to make key-value pair array and at last, use `Object.fromEntries()` method to transform it to required object.

```js
const properties = ['foo', 'bar'];
const query = Object.fromEntries(properties.map((x) => [x, 1]));
console.log(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the recoreds:

Another approach with `reduce` and returning a new object by spreading the object from the former loop.

```js
const
    properties = ['foo', 'bar'],
    result = properties.reduce((object, key) => ({ ...object, [key]: 1 }), {});

console.log(result);
```